# Какой аудио формат поддерживает объект Audio в Safari?

Tags: javascript, html5, safari

Кто-нибудь работал с объектом Audio в Safari? В какой аудио формат он поддерживает? В chrome, opera и ff без проблем подключил. А в safari что-то не получается.

**UPD**

```
<body>
        <audio controls="controls">
                <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                Your browser does not support the audio tag.
        </audio>
</body>
```

Почему-то не работает в safari. Хотя на apple developer написано, что вроде всё должно быть тип топ.

Answer (score 4):

Открываем [эту](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp) ссылку и смотрим поддерживаемые форматы и как эта проблема решается. Если приведенной информации недостаточно - уточняем вопрос и(или) гуглим

Открываем [это](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio) в сафари, если получаем not supported - значит мы тестируем под виндой =) (под виндой не работает практически ничего, еще 1, более суровый пруф http://www.youtube.com/html5)

По сабжу - если работает в хроме, в сафари (чаще всего) можете даже не смотреть

Comment: спасибо за ссылочку. но на этой страничке уже побывал
<audio autoplay preload="auto" controls loop>
<source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
вот что я прописываю в html. в safari по прежнему не работает

Comment: никто не работал?

Comment: Если бы не работал - ссылки не знал бы. Перенесите ваш код в вопрос, и отформатируйте. Чуть позже отвечу (если не ответят до меня)

Comment: я создам новую. у меня нет очков чтобы отвечать.

Comment: Я уже ответил вам в чем ваша проблема как-бы. Для сафари (если это так важно) - да. Но как я уже писал выше, обычно, все что работает в chrome работает и в safari

Comment: просто не совсем понятно. почему safari так обделен. ведь сейчас между браузерами ведутся серьезные соревнования.

Comment: @likdlike - использование сафари под форточками стремиться к 0ю, под родной ОС все работает на ура (если вы, (мат), так и не поняли до сиих пор =))

Answer (score 1):

Пишут не`<source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />`, а `<source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />`